# Practical difference between two Bubble Sort loops

Tags: java, bubble-sort

I have been told by my Teacher that this is is the one and only code for Bubble Sort:

```java
int a[] = {2, 3, 7, 9, 8, 1, 4, 5, 10, 6};
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < a.length - i - 1; j++) {
        if (a[j] > a[j + 1]) {
            int t = a[j];
            a[j] = a[j + 1];
            a[j + 1] = t;
        }
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(a[i] + "\t");
}
```

But I ran the program with a different outer loop:

```java
int b[] = {2, 3, 7, 9, 8, 1, 4, 5, 10, 6};
for (int i = 0; i < b.length - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < b.length - i - 1; j++) {
        if (b[j] > b[j + 1]) {
            int t = b[j];
            b[j] = b[j + 1];
            b[j + 1] = t;
        }
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(b[i] + "\t");
}
```

The Outputs are:

1st Case:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
```

2nd case:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
```

So now I am being told that my code is wrong, even if my output comes correct.

Please, tell me am I entirely wrong??

Comment: It looks like you've almost "improved" the bubble sort to a [cocktail sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocktail_sort).

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen at least two different bubble sort implementations over the years, so the claim that this is the "one and only" is somewhat suspect... In fact, any claim that a particular piece of code is the "one and only" anything should be looked at a bit sideways...

Comment: Please consider visiting academics.se and programmers.se

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both versions will sort correctly. However the 1st version will always do an extra (unneccessary) pass, since its doing N passes, while if one thinks about it, the maximum times an element may change places, is N-1 (that would be when the smallest/largest number is at the wrong end of the array).

So 2nd version is a little more effective, it reduces complexity from approximately O(N*N) to O(N*(N-1)). Which is largely the same.

So, your teacher *should* recognize your code is correct. Since teachers are often stuck in their thinking model, be diplomatic about it when you talk to him, and carefully lead him to the conclusion above that N-1 outer passes are enough.

Answer (score 2):

This is the beginning of a known optimisation of bubble sort: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Optimizing_bubble_sort

Answer (score 0):

Your outer loop doesn't iterate over all elements. Check out b.length-1 `for(int i=0;i<b.length-1;i++)`. That means, that if you have 10 elements you will iterate until 8th element. Since you are using both `<` and `length-1`. If you want to stick with `.length-1`. You should change condition to `i<=b.length-1`.

Comment: Actually, @The Viper **doesn't** need to change his code. It is because the largest elements are properly placed in the beginning, hence total iteration isn't necessary.